# Program I just made is apparently a virus? C++

Tags: c++

Okay so I just made a C++ program that is basically a notebook,
you write stuff in it and it saves it to a .dat file and then you can
read it later.

I compiled it with Microsoft Visual C++ and now I sent it to a friend and it's
saying that it is a virus? I scan it online and it also says that it's a virus.
I don't know why this is happening, as I literally just used some if/else statements, created some strings and used a couple getlines. (and fstream to create the .dat files).

This is the virus report: https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/a1b72280a32915429607fd5abeef1aad4f8310867df1feb7707ea0f7a404026e/analysis/1455735299/

Here is my code. (Its 400+ lines). And I'm almost certain there's nothing wrong
with it. http://pastebin.com/ZwJZrRSu

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: false positive? hard to tell without seeing your code

Comment: you could post it on github or some other code sharing site?

Comment: I noticed that most names start with "Gen" or "Heur". This means it behaves a bit like a common virus. Usually this is the case if it mutates system files after downloading, or encrypts user data based on a downloaded key, things like that. Does your program/code do things like that?

Comment: Well, here you go. I'm almost certain there's nothing wrong with the code though. http://pastebin.com/ZwJZrRSu

Comment: My god! A C++ program that Avast doesn't kill on site!

Comment: Any chance you have a virus on your computer that is adding itself to your compiled executables?

Comment: So, I don't know whether this is contributing to the Virus claim or not, but those `goto` statements are offending my delicate programming sensibilities.

Comment: Off topic: You can eliminate probably 80% of your code by moving all of the monday, tuesday, etc reading and writing code into a function with the day as a parameter.

Comment: Probably the virus scanner is just seeing a certain bit pattern in the executable that matches a pattern seen in viruses. Some minor (and seemingly irrelevant) tweak to your program might change it enough to eliminate the false positive.

Comment: @panthor314: I doubt that seeing the code would be helpful in this case.

Comment: Why is this getting upvotes? O.o

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1513/

Comment: "Detection ratio: 11 / 54" -- if I understand it correctly, that tends to suggest it's a false positive.

Comment: I also thought it was || but it gives the same result either way, I'm not sure why though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably your PC is already infected by a virus, which adds itself to any executable it can find on your machine. That would easily explain this behavior. Try to compile the same program on PC that is clean for sure and check your PC by antivirus.

Comment: I think you're probably right and this is a true positive.

Comment: Actually I made my friend compile my code on his PC and the same Virus Scanner online only found 1 "virus" instead of 11. so yeah I guess I'm infected. Thank you!.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but I think it because you imported kernel32.dll
Again, it is hard to tell without the source
Also take a look at the file detail in the report